# How to split a datetime column efficiently to have timezone in a new column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

So, I am creating a yearly time series data taking DST into consideration as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

sd = '2020-01-01'
ed = '2021-01-01'

df = pd.date_range(sd, ed, freq='0.25H', tz='Europe/Berlin')
df = df.to_frame().reset_index(drop=True)
df.rename(columns={0:'dates'}, inplace=True)
```

The `dates` column also contains the timezone (+1(CET) and +2 (CEST)). Now, I want to split the `dates` column in such a way that in the `dates` column, there is only the date of format (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM) and a new column named `tz` be created and it must have the timezone in the form of a string as either `+01` or `+02`

I did:

```
df['dates'] = df['dates'].apply(lambda t: str(t))
df['tz'] = df['dates'].str.split('+').str[1]
df['tz'] = df['tz'].str.split(':').str[0]
df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dates'])
df['dates'] = df['dates'].apply(lambda t: t.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'))
```

and this gives me the output as follows:

```
dates   tz
2020-01-01 00:00    01
2020-01-01 00:15    01
2020-01-01 00:30    01
2020-01-01 00:45    01
2020-01-01 01:00    01
2020-01-01 01:15    01
2020-01-01 01:30    01
```

Now, I need help with a couple of things:

1. In the `tz` column as you can see the values are only 01, I want to know how can I include the '+' sign in the `tz` column while splitting it?

I know I can do it by doing:

```
df['tz'] = '+' + df['tz'].str.split(':').str[0]
```

But it seems very messy.

2. Is there a more efficient way of splitting the column after creating the original time-series (`pd.date_range(sd, ed, freq='0.25H', tz='Europe/Berlin')`) into the desired output?

**Desired output**

```
dates   tz
2020-01-01 00:00    +01
2020-01-01 00:15    +01
2020-01-01 00:30    +01
2020-01-01 00:45    +01
2020-01-01 01:00    +01
2020-01-01 01:15    +01
2020-01-01 01:30    +01
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, I'd advise against storing datetime type as string, especially those of non-standard format. However, if you insist, you can do:

```
# from the original dataframe
df['tz'] = df['dates'].astype(str).str.extract(r'(\+\d{2})')[0]
df['dates'] = df['dates'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
```

Or only one extract with more complex regex:

```
df['tz'] = ''
df[['dates', 'tz']] = df['dates'].astype(str).str.extract(r'([\d\- \:]+):\d{2}(.+):')
```

Output (head):

```
              dates   tz
0  2020-01-01 00:00  +01
1  2020-01-01 00:15  +01
2  2020-01-01 00:30  +01
3  2020-01-01 00:45  +01
4  2020-01-01 01:00  +01
```

Comment: I will be converting the dates column again, once it is split.

Comment: Can you please explain what does the `r'(\+\d{2})'` expression mean?

Comment: That's regex, you want to capture the `+` character followed by two digits `\d{2}`.

Comment: Thank you very much :)

Comment: Literally : r for regex, () for the delimitation, \ for escaping,  + for the "+" char - d for digit and {2} for two of the d. Everything together: "every string composed of + followed by 2 digits". Edit:oops, too slow:)

Comment: @SimonVanMachin actually I think `r` is for `raw`.